# How to Add Space Between Product Card HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a serious problem when creating a HTML and CSS product card page. I managed to create one product card page successfully as below:

[image: single product card]

However, when I wanted to add more product card next to it, it shows some problem where all the product cards are join together as below:

[image: all product card is joined together]

How shall I make my product card to to work by having 3 in a rows with some spaced between each of it? below is my HTML and CSS code. Thank you and your help really appreciated.

```js
let circle = document.querySelector(".color-option");

        circle.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
            let target = e.target;
            if(target.classList.contains("circle")){
            circle.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
            target.classList.add("active");
            document.querySelector(".main-images .active").classList.remove("active");
            document.querySelector(`.main-images .${target.id}`).classList.add("active");
            }
        });
```

```css
<style>
                 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
                 *{
                     margin: auto;
                     padding: 0;
                     box-sizing: border-box;
                     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
                 }
     
                 body{
                     height: 100vh;
                     display: flex;
                     align-items: center;
                     justify-content: center;
                     background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #43CBFF 10%, #9708CC 100%);
                 }
                 .product-card {
                     position: relative;
                     max-width: 355px;
                     width: 100%;
                     border-radius: 25px;
                     padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
                     background: #fff;
                     box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                     z-index: 3;
                     overflow: hidden;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart{
                     display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                     justify-content: space-between;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart img{
                     height: 60px;
                     width: 60px;
                     object-fit: cover;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart i{
                     font-size: 27px;
                     color: #707070;
                     cursor: pointer;
                     transition: color 0.3s ease;
                }
                 .product-card .logo-cart i:hover{
                     color: #333;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 210px;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images img{
                     position: absolute;
                     height: 300px;
                     width: 300px;
                     object-fit: cover;
                     transform: rotate(18deg);
                     left: 12px;
                     top: -40px;
                     z-index: -1;
                     opacity: 0;
                     transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images img.active{
                     opacity: 1;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details .shoe_name{
                     font-size: 24px;
                     font-weight: 500;
                     color: #161616;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details p{
                     font-size: 12px;
                     font-weight: 400;
                     color: #333;
                     text-align: justify;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details .stars i{
                     margin: 0 -1px;
                     color: #333;
                 }
                 .product-card .color-price .color-option{
                     display: flex;
                     align-items: center;
                 }
                 .color-price{
                     display: flex;
                     justify-content: space-between;
                     align-items: center;
                     margin-top: 10px;
                 }
                 .color-price .color-option .color{
                     font-size: 18px;
                     font-weight: 500;
                     color: #333;
                     margin-right: 8px;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles{
                     display: flex;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle{
                     height: 18px;
                     width: 18px;
                     background: #0071C7;
                     border-radius: 50%;
                     margin: 0 4px;
                     cursor: pointer;
                     transition: all 0.4s ease;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.blue.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                                 0 0 0 4px #0071C7;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.pink{
                     background: #FA1795;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.pink.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                                 0 0 0 4px #FA1795;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow{
                     background: #F5DA00;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                            0 0 0 4px #F5DA00;
                 }
                 .color-price .price{
                     display: flex;
                     flex-direction: column;
                     justify-content: center;
                     align-items: center;
                 }
                 .color-price .price .price_num{
                     font-size: 25px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     color: #707070;
                 }
                 .color-price .price .price_letter{
                     font-size: 10px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     margin-top: -4px;
                     color: #707070;
                 }
                 .product-card .button{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 50px;
                     width: 100%;
                     border-radius: 25px;
                     margin-top: 30px;
                     overflow: hidden;
                }
                 .product-card .button .button-layer{
                     position: absolute;
                     height: 100%;
                     width: 300%;
                     left: -100%;
                     background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#9708CC, #43CBFF,#9708CC, #43CBFF );
                     transition: all 0.4s ease;
                     border-radius: 25PX;
                 }
                 .product-card .button:hover .button-layer{
                     left: 0;
                 }
                 .product-card .button button{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 100%;
                     width: 100%;
                     background: none;
                     outline: none;
                     border: none;
                     font-size: 18px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     color: #fff;
                 }
     </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <body>
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is piggy backing off of what Mhiko said. Put the cards in a parent div and  use display grid with a grid gap. Sizing will need to be adjusted, but this is a quick example.

```css
                 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
                 *{
                     margin: auto;
                     padding: 0;
                     box-sizing: border-box;
                     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
                 }
     
                 body{
                     height: 100vh;
                     display: grid;
                     align-items: center;
                     justify-content: center;
                     background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #43CBFF 10%, #9708CC 100%);
                     grid-gap: 20px
                 }
                 
                 .product-card {
                     position: relative;
                     max-width: 355px;
                     width: 100%;
                     border-radius: 25px;
                     padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
                     background: #fff;
                     box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                     z-index: 3;
                     overflow: hidden;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart{
                     display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                     justify-content: space-between;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart img{
                     height: 60px;
                     width: 60px;
                     object-fit: cover;
                 }
                 .product-card .logo-cart i{
                     font-size: 27px;
                     color: #707070;
                     cursor: pointer;
                     transition: color 0.3s ease;
                }
                 .product-card .logo-cart i:hover{
                     color: #333;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 210px;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images img{
                     position: absolute;
                     height: 300px;
                     width: 300px;
                     object-fit: cover;
                     transform: rotate(18deg);
                     left: 12px;
                     top: -40px;
                     z-index: -1;
                     opacity: 0;
                     transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                 }
                 .product-card .main-images img.active{
                     opacity: 1;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details .shoe_name{
                     font-size: 24px;
                     font-weight: 500;
                     color: #161616;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details p{
                     font-size: 12px;
                     font-weight: 400;
                     color: #333;
                     text-align: justify;
                 }
                 .product-card .shoe-details .stars i{
                     margin: 0 -1px;
                     color: #333;
                 }
                 .product-card .color-price .color-option{
                     display: flex;
                     align-items: center;
                 }
                 .color-price{
                     display: flex;
                     justify-content: space-between;
                     align-items: center;
                     margin-top: 10px;
                 }
                 .color-price .color-option .color{
                     font-size: 18px;
                     font-weight: 500;
                     color: #333;
                     margin-right: 8px;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles{
                     display: flex;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle{
                     height: 18px;
                     width: 18px;
                     background: #0071C7;
                     border-radius: 50%;
                     margin: 0 4px;
                     cursor: pointer;
                     transition: all 0.4s ease;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.blue.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                                 0 0 0 4px #0071C7;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.pink{
                     background: #FA1795;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.pink.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                                 0 0 0 4px #FA1795;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow{
                     background: #F5DA00;
                 }
                 .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow.active{
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                            0 0 0 4px #F5DA00;
                 }
                 .color-price .price{
                     display: flex;
                     flex-direction: column;
                     justify-content: center;
                     align-items: center;
                 }
                 .color-price .price .price_num{
                     font-size: 25px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     color: #707070;
                 }
                 .color-price .price .price_letter{
                     font-size: 10px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     margin-top: -4px;
                     color: #707070;
                 }
                 .product-card .button{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 50px;
                     width: 100%;
                     border-radius: 25px;
                     margin-top: 30px;
                     overflow: hidden;
                }
                 .product-card .button .button-layer{
                     position: absolute;
                     height: 100%;
                     width: 300%;
                     left: -100%;
                     background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#9708CC, #43CBFF,#9708CC, #43CBFF );
                     transition: all 0.4s ease;
                     border-radius: 25PX;
                 }
                 .product-card .button:hover .button-layer{
                     left: 0;
                 }
                 .product-card .button button{
                     position: relative;
                     height: 100%;
                     width: 100%;
                     background: none;
                     outline: none;
                     border: none;
                     font-size: 18px;
                     font-weight: 600;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     color: #fff;
                 }
                 .parent {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-gap: 20px;
              }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
            <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
            <!--<img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/blue.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="pink" class="pink" src="images/pink.png" alt="blue">-->
            <!--<img id="yellow" class="yellow" src="images/yellow.png" alt="blue">-->
            </div>
            <div class="shoe-details">
            <span class="shoe_name">ADDIDAS GAZE ZX</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorenm i amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ea, ducimus!</p>
            <div class="stars">
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
            <div class="color-option">
                <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                <div class="circles">
                <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                <span class="circle pink " id="pink"></span>
                <span class="circle yellow " id="yellow"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use flexbox or use display: grid, and then to show 3 columns in a row, you use grid-template-columns. Then, you can use grid gap for spacing. Hope this help!

parent div:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px
}
```

Comment: hi. it seems that your code does not work to my web page. is there anything else? Thank you very much for the help and I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Check the answer below, also... it's better if you added a wrapper or a container for your product cards.